# What is the best way to relate a table through another to user directly?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

The system of three tables

user table

> users - id, name, email, user_type (student, teacher)

events table

> events - id, student_id, teacher_id, meeting_id, event_details(JSON)

Meeting table

> id, meeting_string(unique random string), start_time, meeting_details(API response JSON)

What is the best way to get teacher Meetings?

I did it by

```php
return Meeting::whereHas('event', function ($q){
   $q->where('teacher_id', $this->id);
})->get();
```

but it's not supporting create([]) throwing create on collection error.

I could get the tutor through this method on meeting model

```php
public function tutor(): HasOne
{
    return $this->event->tutor();
}
```

It will be helpful if the solution supports `teacherMeetings()->create([])`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon The teacher can create events and every event is connected to a meeting (jitsi / zoom) so that the student and teacher can join through the meeting. and the relation is user->events and Events->meeting, there's no direct relation between user to meeting. So how relate meeting and user through eloquent?

Comment: also updated the question with some more details, Please check @zahidhasanemon

Comment: To make things easier for you moving forward, have you considered just creating a `teacher_id` column under the `meetings` table?

Comment: `but it's not supporting create([]) throwing create on collection error.` That's because you are returning a collection, looks like you want to set up a Many to Many polymorphic relationship. This should allow you to attach both a teacher and student to the meeting.  `$teacher->meetings()->attach($meeting);`

Comment: @fufubrocat initially I had the same relation, teacher_id in meetings table. Since the event already has the connection between meetings and users removed it. Is that the only or best way to solve it?

Comment: @Second2None We have many to many between students and events already. But not for the tutor since event - tutor is one to one connection same to the meeting. Any suggestion to make it simple? am I missing anything?

Comment: found an indirect solution. removed `get()` from `Meeting::whereHas..` it works. It acts as a relation.